# Performance drop returning cursor with union all

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm facing unsolvable and impossible performace drop while using UNION ALL with two sub-queries in one cursor (at least I think that's the problem). PL/SQL Developer just freezes when opening cursor results in test window.

If I turn off no matter which sub-query - everything works fine.

If I take the whole query out of cursor to regular SQL Query windows - everything is okay without any need to turn off some parts.

Procedure structure is down below, looking forward any help:

```
procedure p_proc(p_param varchar2,
                 outcur  out sys_refcursor) is
begin
  open outcur for
    select *
      from (select -- visible cols
                   si.item_full_name
                 , si.final_price
                 , si.full_price
                 , si.receipt_num
                 , si.receipt_date
                 , si.vendor_code
                 , case when det.br_summary is null and mr.motiv_rate_value is not null then mr.motiv_rate_value
                        when det.br_summary is not null then det.br_summary
                    end personal_bonus_amount
                 , case when det.br_summary is null and mr.motiv_rate_value is not null then 1
                        when det.br_summary is not null then det.cross_sale_kt
                    end personal_bonus_koeff
                 -- service cols
                 , case when det.br_summary is null and mr.motiv_rate_value is not null then 'approximate'
                        when det.br_summary is not null then 'definite'
                    end personal_bonus_type
                 , coalesce(det.sale_stream, mr.sale_stream, 'Not defined') item_group_name
                 , si.operation_type
                 , si.src
                 -- pagination
                 , row_number() over (order by si.receipt_date desc) rn 
              from (-- curr day
                    select b.cost final_price
                         , case when b.discount = 0 then null else b.price
                            end full_price
                         , b.doc_number receipt_num
                         , b.receipt_date receipt_date
                         , i.item_code vendor_code
                         , i.full_name item_full_name
                         , b.subsite code_op
                         , b.operator_id
                         , to_char(b.businessday, 'yyyymm') sale_period
                         , b.oper_type operation_type
                         , 'bill' src
                      from scheme.bills b
                      join scheme.items i on i.item_code = b.item
                     where b.businessday = trunc(p_date_to)
                       and b.subsite = p_office_id
                       and b.operator_id = p_emp_id
                    union all
                    -- prev days
                    select l.txn_amount final_price
                         , case when l.disc = 0 then null else l.price
                             end full_price
                         , t.receipt_num receipt_num
                         , t.ts receipt_date
                         , i.item_code vendor_code
                         , i.full_name item_full_name
                         , s.office_code code_op
                         , e.emp_code operator_id
                         , to_char(l.dt,'yyyymm') sale_period
                         , l.txn_type operation_type
                         , 'txn' src
                      from scheme.txn t
                      join scheme.txn_lines l on t.rtl_txn_id = l.rtl_txn_id
                      join scheme.items i on l.item_id = i.item_id
                      join scheme.offices s on t.subsite_id = s.subsite_id
                      join scheme.employees e on t.employee_id = e.employee_id
                     where t.ts between trunc(p_date_from) and trunc(p_date_to)
                       and t.subsite_id = v_op_id
                       and t.employee_id = v_emp_id
                 ) si
             /* fact */
             left join scheme.sales_details det on si.sale_period = det.period
                                               and si.code_op = det.op_code
                                               and ltrim(si.operator_id,'0') = ltrim(det.tab_num,'0')
                                               and si.receipt_num = det.rcpt_num
                                               and si.vendor_code = det.item_article
             /* prognosis */
             left join scheme.rates mr on si.sale_period = mr.motiv_rate_period
                                      and si.code_op = mr.code_op
                                      and si.vendor_code = mr.code_1c
            where 1 = 1
              and si.final_price between nvl(p_price_from, si.final_price) and nvl(p_price_to, si.final_price)
              /* if no filters */
              and (item_group_cnt = 0 or coalesce(det.sale_stream, mr.sale_stream, 'Not defined') in (select * from table(p_item_group)))
              and si.receipt_num = nvl(p_receipt_num, si.receipt_num)                                        
           )
     where rn between p_page_num * p_page_size + 1 and (p_page_num + 1) * p_page_size;
end;
```

**UPD** Explain plan for the whole query used in a cursor:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id   | Operation                                             | Name                           | Rows | Bytes | Cost | Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    0 | SELECT STATEMENT                                      |                                |   10 | 32810 |   62 | 00:00:01 |
|  * 1 |   VIEW                                                |                                |   10 | 32810 |   62 | 00:00:01 |
|  * 2 |    WINDOW SORT PUSHED RANK                            |                                |    2 |  2956 |   62 | 00:00:01 |
|    3 |     NESTED LOOPS OUTER                                |                                |    2 |  2956 |   61 | 00:00:01 |
|    4 |      NESTED LOOPS OUTER                               |                                |    2 |  2826 |   53 | 00:00:01 |
|    5 |       VIEW                                            |                                |    2 |  2728 |   46 | 00:00:01 |
|    6 |        UNION-ALL                                      |                                |      |       |      |          |
|    7 |         NESTED LOOPS                                  |                                |    1 |   138 |   32 | 00:00:01 |
|    8 |          NESTED LOOPS                                 |                                |    1 |   138 |   32 | 00:00:01 |
|    9 |           PARTITION RANGE SINGLE                      |                                |    1 |    66 |   29 | 00:00:01 |
| * 10 |            TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID BATCHED  | F003_BILL                      |    1 |    66 |   29 | 00:00:01 |
| * 11 |             INDEX RANGE SCAN                          | IX_SUBSITE_DOCNUM_BUSINDAY_SEQ |    1 |       |    5 | 00:00:01 |
| * 12 |           INDEX RANGE SCAN                            | IX_D001_CODE_1C_ITEM_ID        |    1 |       |    2 | 00:00:01 |
|   13 |          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID                  | D001_ITEM                      |    1 |    72 |    3 | 00:00:01 |
|   14 |         NESTED LOOPS                                  |                                |    1 |   183 |   14 | 00:00:01 |
|   15 |          NESTED LOOPS                                 |                                |    1 |   183 |   14 | 00:00:01 |
|   16 |           NESTED LOOPS                                |                                |    1 |   104 |   12 | 00:00:01 |
|   17 |            NESTED LOOPS                               |                                |    1 |    70 |    7 | 00:00:01 |
|   18 |             NESTED LOOPS                              |                                |    1 |    30 |    4 | 00:00:01 |
|   19 |              TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID              | D005_EMPLOYEE                  |    1 |    18 |    3 | 00:00:01 |
| * 20 |               INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                       | PK_D005                        |    1 |       |    2 | 00:00:01 |
|   21 |              TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID              | D018_SUBSITE                   |    1 |    12 |    1 | 00:00:01 |
| * 22 |               INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                       | PK_D018                        |    1 |       |    0 | 00:00:01 |
|   23 |             PARTITION RANGE ITERATOR                  |                                |    1 |    40 |    3 | 00:00:01 |
|   24 |              PARTITION HASH SINGLE                    |                                |    1 |    40 |    3 | 00:00:01 |
| * 25 |               TABLE ACCESS FULL                       | F007_RTL_TXN                   |    1 |    40 |    3 | 00:00:01 |
| * 26 |            TABLE ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID BATCHED | F008_RTL_TXN_LI                |    1 |    34 |    5 | 00:00:01 |
| * 27 |             INDEX RANGE SCAN                          | IX_F008_RTL_TXN_ID             |    7 |       |    3 | 00:00:01 |
| * 28 |           INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                           | PK_D001                        |    1 |       |    1 | 00:00:01 |
|   29 |          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID                  | D001_ITEM                      |    1 |    79 |    2 | 00:00:01 |
| * 30 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED             | T_OP_MOTIVATION_RATE_MYRTK     |    1 |    49 |    7 | 00:00:01 |
| * 31 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN                               | IDX02_CODE_OP_1C               |    3 |       |    3 | 00:00:01 |
| * 32 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED              | DET_SALES_PPT_DWH              |    1 |    65 |    4 | 00:00:01 |
| * 33 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN                                | IDX_03_RCPT_NUM                |    3 |       |    2 | 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
------------------------------------------
* 1 - filter("RN">=1 AND "RN"<=10)
* 2 - filter(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY INTERNAL_FUNCTION("SI"."RECEIPT_DATE") DESC )<=10)
* 10 - filter("F003"."OPERATOR_ID"='000189513' AND "F003"."COST">=TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR("F003"."COST")) AND "F003"."COST"<=TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR("F003"."COST")))
* 11 - access("F003"."SUBSITE"='S165' AND "F003"."BUSINESSDAY"=TO_DATE(' 2021-11-23 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
* 11 - filter("F003"."BUSINESSDAY"=TO_DATE(' 2021-11-23 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND "F003"."DOC_NUMBER" IS NOT NULL)
* 12 - access("I"."D001_CODE_1C"="F003"."ITEM")
* 12 - filter("I"."D001_CODE_1C" IS NOT NULL)
* 20 - access("E"."EMPLOYEE_ID"=3561503543)
* 22 - access("S"."SUBSITE_ID"=29260)
* 25 - filter("T"."EMPLOYEE_ID"=3561503543 AND "T"."SUBSITE_ID"=29260 AND "T"."F007_TS"<=TO_DATE(' 2021-11-23 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND "T"."F007_RCPT_NUM_1C" IS NOT NULL)
* 26 - filter("L"."F008_AMOUNT">=TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR("L"."F008_AMOUNT")) AND "L"."F008_AMOUNT"<=TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR("L"."F008_AMOUNT")))
* 27 - access("T"."RTL_TXN_ID"="L"."RTL_TXN_ID")
* 28 - access("L"."ITEM_ID"="I"."ITEM_ID")
* 30 - filter("SI"."SALE_PERIOD"="MR"."MOTIV_RATE_PERIOD"(+))
* 31 - access("SI"."CODE_OP"="MR"."CODE_OP"(+) AND "SI"."VENDOR_CODE"="MR"."CODE_1C"(+))
* 32 - filter("SI"."CODE_OP"="DET"."OP_CODE"(+) AND "SI"."VENDOR_CODE"="DET"."ITEM_ARTICLE"(+) AND "DET"."ITEM_ARTICLE"(+) IS NOT NULL AND "DET"."PERIOD"(+)=TO_NUMBER("SI"."SALE_PERIOD") AND
  LTRIM("SI"."OPERATOR_ID",'0')=LTRIM("DET"."TAB_NUM_RTK"(+),'0'))
* 33 - access("SI"."RECEIPT_NUM"="DET"."RCPT_NUM"(+))
* 33 - filter("DET"."RCPT_NUM"(+) IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: please run an explain plan on the select and post the results

Comment: explain plan added, performance stays good no matter what "page size" used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Actual solution**

Managed to get procedure execution plan from DBA. The problem was that optimizer chose another index for joining scheme.sales_details table when executing query inside the procedure. Added INDEX HINT with the same index which was used in regular query and everything works just fine.

**Deprecated ideas down below**

As far as I understood the problem is in Oracle optimizer which "thought" that doing UNION ALL first is better than pushing predicate into the sub-query. Separating this union into two single queries make him push pred without any hesitations.

Probably this can be fixed by playing with hints, that's wip for now.

Temporary workaround is to regroup the query, going from this structure

```
    select *
      from (select row_number() rn
                 , u.*
              from (select * 
                      from first_query
                     union all
                    select * 
                      from second_query) u
                -- some joins
              join first_table ft
              join second_table st
                -- predicate block
             where 1=1
               and a = b
            )
     where rn between c and d;
```

to this

```
select *
      from (select row_number() rn
                 , u.*
              from (select * 
                      from first_query) u
                -- some joins
              join first_table ft
              join second_table st
                -- predicate block
             where 1=1
               and a = b
             union all
            select row_number() rn
                 , u.*
              from (select * 
                      from second_query) u
                -- some joins
              join first_table ft
              join second_table st
                -- predicate block
             where 1=1
               and a = b
            )
     where rn between c and d;
```

That's not the perfect solution cause it doubles the JOIN section but at least it works.